# Default selection in details list fluent ui

Tags: reactjs, fluentui-react

How to make first item to be selected by default in details list as soon as component is rendered.

```
onSelectionChanged: () => {
            const selectedSamples = selection.getSelection() as IClientSample[];
                setAnnotationSampleListState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, selectedSamples: selectedSamples}));
                
            }
        }
<DetailsList
 items={state.items}
 columns={state.columns}
 setKey={"id"}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had your same need and I resolved using the `Selection`'s `onItemsChanged` event.

Following there is a sample code that you can adapt to your needs

```js
const selection: Selection = new Selection({
    onItemsChanged: () => selection.selectToIndex(0)
});

<DetailsList
   items={items}
   selection={selection}
   columns={itemListcolumns}
   selectionMode={SelectionMode.single}
   layoutMode={DetailsListLayoutMode.justified}
   isHeaderVisible={true} />
```